# Resources on understanding the Orchestrated objective reduction

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, biology, perception

I was trying to understand the mathematics behind the theory of [*Orchestrated objective reduction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction), and clearly, first I read the original paper of Penrose & Hameroff. Then I tried some other related papers (reviews, critics, etc.), yet, I could not find any straightforward math behind this theory in any of my searchings.

Are there any references and resources on the mathematics of Orchestrated objective reduction?

Comment: Seems more appropriate to [psychology.se]

Comment: @StephenG That is exactly why I asked this question on PE. Yes, clearly this is a theory about consciousness, but it has physics and math behind it (*quantum information theory, and quantum gravity*), which I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the criticisms that a straightforward mathematical description just doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, but then I watched some of the conferences of Hameroff, which he explains a bit more. I was wondering if a text - reference of those explanations exist or not. @knzhou

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine But Penrose assumes that a wavefunction spontaneously collapses when it reaches a certain energy caused by quantum gravity. Is there any resource to understand the physics behind it?